# Bundling assets with jspm/systemjs

Tags: image, fonts, assets, systemjs, jspm

I'm currently developing a react application using jspm/systemjs.

I've been looking for a way to bundle assets inside of an bundle-sfx (build) file.
I have some images, fonts and potentially svg to add into my application. Currently the build file link those by urls into my sources.

But my goal is to be able to provide a single file to load in the html, which also bundle those assets; or at least package all those assets into a  common folder from which I could serve as is.

For now I'm using [systemjs/plugin-css](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-css), which concatenates all the css into a minified file.

I've looked at those plugins: [vuzonp/systemjs-plugin-svg](https://github.com/vuzonp/systemjs-plugin-svg), [systemjs/plugin-image](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-image), and [systemjs/system-font](https://github.com/systemjs/system-font).

But from what i read [from that thread](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-css/issues/61), it is not easily doable nor even possible at the moment.

---

- Does anyone know how to do that, or could point me at the right direction ?
- Does a plugin exist which would handle assets as undiscriminated files ?
- Do I have to process each kind (mime-type) of file differently ?

Comment: how do you import image file in systemjs i want to import svg file but it dosent let me